# Dreamweaver Centering Divtag : Creating a header box

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver, center

Im creating a dreamweaver site and in my template i have made a css style sheet with a div tag #HeaderBox. I want this to be a box that is 40% the size of the screen, a specified amount of pixels is fine. I want to center this box, but the   tag isn't working
Here is the code for the template:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link href="../Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="HeaderBox"></div>
</center>
</body>
<html>
```

Here is the code for styles.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#HeaderBox {
font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: capitalize;
text-decoration: underline;
background-position: center 40px;
border: 2px groove #CC6;
top: 0px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: 10%;
width: 40%;
padding: 0%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your #HeaderBox CSS

```
Margin: 0 auto;
```

What does the above do/ mean? Well first we declare that we need to adjust the margins in question. The '0' is actually shorthand CSS in play here (ie: you could do Margin: 0 auto 0 auto;) which would accomplish the same thing. But the 0 in question declares the top and bottom margins, the auto tells the browser fit me in with the space you have around said element.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, however what is the "0" for, i tried it without the "0" and it still worked.

Comment: @Monacraft margin:0 auto; = the top and bottom margin 0, and the left and right margin auto. It just shorthand for CSS.